# Browse website folder in JAVA

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom

In my JAVA application, I need to access to an online website (let's take the example www.website.com/folder) and then check for each folder website.com/folder/folder1 , website.com/folder/folder2 , ..) all the .txt files existing in this folder and read the content.

I have a string code and I need to check in which folder and text file it exists.

It's possible to do that in JAVA ? Can you suggest me a library ?

Comment: Websites don't have folders. (Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ a folder?)

Comment: what if the website won't allow you to freely check for txt files ? is the target website yours?

Comment: Exactly, the target website is mine and it contains .txt log files (That I can access to)

Comment: If the website is yours, you have to create a page that requests the server for the logs and displays them as htmls or similar. What server are you using? Your server can access folders normally using the File object.

Comment: Jsoup or grep4j would be a good way to parse html files in Java ?